# How does Linux bash/shell read the command we give to it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example, if I send `bash -c " echo "$S" "`

How does it read the command, from left to right, or read from left and right together to middle? or else?

If it's not too much, can you list a step by step, like how the linux bash/shell read and treat every single character and symbol it receives?

Comment: The shell parsing and expansion steps are thoroughly described [in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html)

Comment: @thatotherguy that means a lot to me, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are issuing this command from a *bash* shell, and the variable `S` contains the value `x       y`:

First, the variable is expanded, which would leave you with

```
bash -c " echo "x      y" "
```

Then, the quotes are expanded. Therefore, you are left with 4 token:

- bash
- -c
- `echo x` (one leading space)
- `y`  (i.e. y followed by one space)

Next, another bash is started, with the arguments `-c`,  `echo x` and `y` .

This bash-subshell would now execute the echo command and print `x y`.